# How can I get the results from one org-mode cell as a table to process in another?

Tags: sparql, org-mode

In my document I create a first cell block for retrieving data:

```
#+name: raw-dataset
#+BEGIN_SRC sparql :url https://query.wikidata.org/sparql :format text/csv :cache yes :exports both
SELECT ?wLabel ?pLabel
WHERE
{
  ?p wdt:P31 wd:Q98270496 .
  ?p wdt:P1416 ?w .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
ORDER BY ASC(?wLabel) ASC(?pLabel)
LIMIT 10
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS[7981b64721a5ffc448aa7da773ce07ea8dbaf8ac]: raw-dataset
| wLabel                                        | pLabel       |
|-----------------------------------------------+--------------|
| Q105775472                                    | NFDI4Health  |
| Q1117007                                      | NFDI4Health  |
| Q115254989                                    | NFDI4Objects |
| Q1205424                                      | NFDI4Objects |
| Q17575706                                     | NFDI4Objects |
| Academy of Sciences and Humanities in Hamburg | Text+        |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | NFDI4Culture |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | NFDI4Memory  |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | NFDI4Objects |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | Text+        |
```

This works as expected but I want to get rid of those lines starting with `Q1....`.
For didactical reasons I *do not* want to do this in the SPARQL query but in a second cell.

Now the trouble starts.
When I read in the results from `raw-dataset` everything is written in *one line*. There are no end of line characters etc. used.

```
#+begin_src sh :var data=raw-dataset :exports both :results output raw
echo ${data}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
Q105775472 NFDI4Health Q1117007 NFDI4Health Q115254989 NFDI4Objects Q1205424 NFDI4Objects Q17575706 NFDI4Objects Academy of Sciences and Humanities in Hamburg Text+ Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz NFDI4Culture Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz NFDI4Memory Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz NFDI4Objects Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz Text+
```

So, that is why obviously my attempt to clean the data set with e.g. `grep` cannot work

```
#+begin_src sh :var data=raw-dataset :exports both
echo ${data} | grep -L -E "Q[1-9]"
#+end_src
```

I do not want to alter the result output of `raw-dataset` since exporting this to e.g. a website puts it as a nice table:

[image: exported document]

*Question*: How can I keep the table formatted result of `raw-dataset` but still be able to clean the data in an easy second step; or how can I read in the results of `raw-dataset` as structured table?

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally I found out, when I state the `shebang` to e.g. `zsh`, then I get the desired result:

```
#+begin_src sh :var data=raw-dataset :shebang "#!/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh" :exports both
echo ${data}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| Q105775472                                    | NFDI4Health  |
| Q1117007                                      | NFDI4Health  |
| Q115254989                                    | NFDI4Objects |
| Q1205424                                      | NFDI4Objects |
| Q17575706                                     | NFDI4Objects |
| Academy of Sciences and Humanities in Hamburg | Text+        |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | NFDI4Culture |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | NFDI4Memory  |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | NFDI4Objects |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | Text+        |
```