# Why is grep only partially working in an org-mode source block?

Tags: grep, org-mode

This is a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77029806/how-can-i-get-the-results-from-one-org-mode-cell-as-a-table-to-process-in-anothe) about cleaning a SPARQL-dataset.

The dataset is gained by this cell:

```
#+name: raw-dataset
#+BEGIN_SRC sparql :url https://query.wikidata.org/sparql :format text/csv :cache yes :exports both
SELECT ?wLabel ?pLabel
WHERE
{
  ?p wdt:P31 wd:Q98270496 .
  ?p wdt:P1416 ?w .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
ORDER BY ASC(?wLabel) ASC(?pLabel)
LIMIT 10
#+END_SRC


#+RESULTS[7981b64721a5ffc448aa7da773ce07ea8dbaf8ac]: raw-dataset
| wLabel                                        | pLabel       |
|-----------------------------------------------+--------------|
| Q105775472                                    | NFDI4Health  |
| Q1117007                                      | NFDI4Health  |
| Q115254989                                    | NFDI4Objects |
| Q1205424                                      | NFDI4Objects |
| Q17575706                                     | NFDI4Objects |
| Academy of Sciences and Humanities in Hamburg | Text+        |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | NFDI4Culture |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | NFDI4Memory  |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | NFDI4Objects |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | Text+        |
```

As a second step I take a look at the data using `zsh`:

```
#+begin_src sh :var data=raw-dataset :shebang "#!/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh" :exports both
echo ${data}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| Q105775472                                    | NFDI4Health  |
| Q1117007                                      | NFDI4Health  |
| Q115254989                                    | NFDI4Objects |
| Q1205424                                      | NFDI4Objects |
| Q17575706                                     | NFDI4Objects |
| Academy of Sciences and Humanities in Hamburg | Text+        |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | NFDI4Culture |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | NFDI4Memory  |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | NFDI4Objects |
| Academy of Sciences and Literature Mainz      | Text+        |
```

All fine and I can start with the cleaning part, getting rid of all lines containing `Q....`:

```
#+begin_src sh :var data=raw-dataset :exports both :shebang "#!/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh"
echo ${data} | grep -L -E "Q[1-9]"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
```

Somehow using the `-L` does not work.
But without (`-L`) I get the results as expected from the code:

```
#+begin_src sh :var data=raw-dataset :shebang "#!/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh" :exports both
echo ${data} | grep -E "Q[1-9]"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| Q105775472 | NFDI4Health  |
| Q1117007   | NFDI4Health  |
| Q115254989 | NFDI4Objects |
| Q1205424   | NFDI4Objects |
| Q17575706  | NFDI4Objects |
```

*Question*: Why is `-L` not working and how can I get rid of the lines starting with `Q....`?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Comment: Use `grep -v` to exclude lines.   `grep -L` excludes entire files, which doesn't make sense in a pipeline.

Comment: Of course ..... do you want to turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude lines beginning with Q and then a digit:

- `... | grep -v '^Q[0-9]'`
- `... | grep -Pv '^Q\d'`

As mentioned in the comment, `-L` is a rare commandline option (`--files-without-match`), for excluding entire files.  `-v` is quite common, for excluding lines matching the pattern or patterns.  The `v`, as mentioned in `man grep` is from `--invert-match`